# Conditionally define color channel on multi-line graph

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have a graph with two lines, I want the option to toggle a `param` to combine the two lines into one.

Vega-lite allows you to encode a field with a condition, but I can't seem to "define nothing" if the condition fails. I can give a `value: red` but that just sets both lines to the same color, or `value: false/null` which removes the lines entirely.

The [condition docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/condition.html) describe the "else" fields as optional, but without any `value` or `field` I never see two lines -- which seems like the channel is never defined.

Eg, I have this graph:

[image]

And when I toggle the "combine" checkbox, I would like to get this (the same effect as simply not defining a 'color' channel):

[image]

Instead I get this:

[image]

Example spec for use on https://vega.github.io/editor/

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"y": -1, "x": 1, "name": "north"},
      {"y": 2, "x": 2, "name": "north"},
      {"y": 0, "x": 3, "name": "north"},
      {"y": -3, "x": 1, "name": "south"},
      {"y": 1, "x": 2, "name": "south"},
      {"y": 4, "x": 3, "name": "south"}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "condition": {"param": "combine", "field": "name"},
      "value": "red",
    },
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "median",
      "field": "y",
      "scale": {"domain": [-10, 10]},
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  },
  "height": "container",
  "layer": [{"mark": {"interpolate": "basis", "type": "line"}}],
  "params": [
    {
      "bind": {"input": "checkbox"},
      "name": "combine",
      "value": "Yes"
    }
  ],
  "width": 300
}
```

Comment: Are you open to doing this in Vega rather than VL?

Comment: Probably not as the vega spec is generated via a intermediate library that wraps vega-lite, though maybe I can hack the spec after its generated... I guess it depends how different the solution is.

Comment: VL compiles to Vega under the hood. If you need to use VL, then you might need to rethink the approach. Let me have a think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can do.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"y": -1, "x": 1, "name": "north"},
      {"y": 2, "x": 2, "name": "north"},
      {"y": 0, "x": 3, "name": "north"},
      {"y": -3, "x": 1, "name": "south"},
      {"y": 1, "x": 2, "name": "south"},
      {"y": 4, "x": 3, "name": "south"}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "median",
      "field": "y",
      "scale": {"domain": [-10, 10]},
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  },
  "height": "container",
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "combine?true:false"}],
      "mark": {"interpolate": "basis", "type": "line"},
      "encoding": {"color": {"field": "name"}}
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "combine?false:true"}],
      "mark": {
        "interpolate": "basis",
        "type": "line",
        "color": "red"
      }
    }
  ],
  "params": [{"bind": {"input": "checkbox"}, "name": "combine", "value": true}],
  "width": 300
}
```